# Conditional code for different API levels (React Native Android)

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

So, my app is using minSdkVersion 16, and I would like to use a library that only supports version 18 and up.

The feature would be used in only a small part of the app, and I would be fine with just disabling that feature for Android users on API levels 16 & 17.

Is it fine for me to force install the library with `tools:overrideLibrary` and just check the version number at runtime with `Platform.Version` to determine if that feature should be used or not. Will that cause some unexpected issues?

Anyone done something like this in RN?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, we decided against using said library. Did not do a deep dive into this so the above solution might work, but you would have to try and see for yourself.